# Mistake in converting Riemann Sum

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum

EDIT: I know how to integrate the last part. I'm just try to find mistake in converting Sum to integral

Question:

> $$a_n=\left(\left(1+\left(\frac1n\right)^2\right)\left(1+\left(\frac2n\right)^2\right)\cdots\left(1+\left(\frac{n}n\right)^2\right)\right)^n$$ find
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{-1/n^2}$$

My Approach:
Let $$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{-1/n^2}$$ I Converted this to 
$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}{-1\over n}\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\ln\left(1+{k^2\over n^2}\right) \right)$$

and then to (here's where i think the mistake is in conversion, not integration):

$$\ln y=-\int_0^1\ln(1+x^2)dx$$

However, the answer is $\ln y=1/2-\ln2$

Please the help me find mistake

Comment: what is the function here?

Comment: Use **\left( $\ldots$ \right)** for appropriate size in brackets. For example, instead of $(1 + \dfrac{k^2}{n^2})$ you could generate $\left(1+\dfrac{k^2}{n^2}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, your book is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct but..

By parts,

$$\int_0^1\ln (1+x^2)dx=$$
$$[x\ln (1+x^2)]_0^1-2\int_0^1\frac {x^2+1-1}{1+x^2}dx =$$

$$\ln (2)-2+2\arctan (1) =$$
$$\ln (2)-2+\frac {\pi}{2} =-\ln y$$